# Dynamically arrange some elements around a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a function to arrange some elements around a circle.
result should be something like :

[image]

Comment: @camus my real problem is that i don't know trigonometry ;)

Comment: only for 4 elements or for `n` elements in same distance?

Comment: @Neysor `n` element with different distance.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Here's some code that should help you:

```
var numElements = 4,
    angle = 0
    step = (2*Math.PI) / numElements;
for(var i = 0; i < numElements.length; i++) {
    var x = container_width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = container_height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    angle += step;
}
```

It is not complete but should give you a good start.

---

Update: Here's something that actually works:

```
var radius = 200; // radius of the circle
var fields = $('.field'),
    container = $('#container'),
    width = container.width(),
    height = container.height(),
    angle = 0,
    step = (2*Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
    var x = Math.round(width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width()/2),
        y = Math.round(height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height()/2);
    $(this).css({
        left: x + 'px',
        top: y + 'px'
    });
    angle += step;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/LPh33/
Here's an [improved version](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/LPh33/4/) where you can change the element count.

Comment: how do you know where the cycle is ?

Comment: You need to add the circle's coordinates, and subtract half of the element's dimensions, from `x` and `y` yourself.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That's Ok friend, just i don't want to use relative positioning. how to do that if `fields` and `cycle` are not in the same container

Comment: I really want to learn about this. Could you please some explanation with mathematical formula on your answer. Pretty Please :)

Comment: @Starx: Sounds like something worth a bounty ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Common a diamond after your name and you are still greedy?? :P

Comment: This is great but does the variable "angle" hold an angular measurement? Doesn't it instead hold a value expressed radians?

Answer (score 14):

For an element around a centre at (*x*, *y*), distance *r*, the element's centre should be positioned at:

```
(x + r cos(2kπ/n), y + r sin(2kπ/n))
```

where *n* is the number of elements, and *k* is the "number" of the element you're currently positioning (between 1 and *n* inclusive).

Comment: `xy` means the same thing as `x * y` in mathematics.

Comment: What is the formula for placing them in an ellipse?

Answer (score 6):

I've combined ThiefMaster's fiddle with the jQuery pointAt plugin:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BananaAcid/nytN6/

```
the code is somewhat like above.
might be interesting to some of you.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Arrange Elements In Circle (Javascript)

```
function arrangeElementsInCircle (elements, x, y, r) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].scaleX = 1 / elements.length
        elements[i].scaleY = 1 / elements.length
        elements[i].x = (x + r * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI) * i/elements.length))
        elements[i].y = (y + r * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI) * i/store.length))
    }
}
```

Where `x,y` is point co-ordinates and `elements` is array of elements to be placed and `r` is radius.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript only version of thiefmaster's answer**

```
function distributeFields(deg){
  deg = deg || 0;
  var radius = 200;
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field'), //using queryselector instead of $ to select items 
      container = document.querySelector('#container'),
      width = container.offsetWidth,  //offsetWidth gives the width of the container
      height = container.offsetHeight,
      angle = deg || Math.PI * 3.5,
      step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
      console.log(width, height)
      
     //using forEach loop on a NodeList instead of a Jquery .each, 
     //so we can now use "field" as an iterator instead of $(this)

      fields.forEach((field)=>{
        var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - field.offsetWidth/2);
        var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - field.offsetHeight/2);
        console.log(x, y)
        field.style.left = x + 'px';  //adding inline style to the document (field)
        field.style.top= y + 'px';

        angle += step;
      })
}

distributeFields();
```

Comment: Please add comments to your code to explain your answer

Comment: Thank you, added the comments

Answer (score 0):

In the html there is the `data-gap` attribute where you can enter the gap between center circle and small circles.

```js
var cs = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
var center = document.getElementById("center");
var amount = cs.length;
var startAngle = -90;
var angleToAdd = 360 / amount;
var offsetPx = -(cs[0].offsetWidth / 2) + (center.offsetWidth / 2);
var radius = (center.offsetWidth / 2) + (cs[0].offsetWidth / 2) + parseInt(center.dataset.gap);

for (i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
  angle = startAngle * Math.PI / 180;
  var x = (radius * Math.cos(angle)) + offsetPx;
  var y = (radius * Math.sin(angle)) + offsetPx;
  cs[i].style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)";
  startAngle += angleToAdd;
}
```

```css
#display {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#center {
  width: 130px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: gold;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.c {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: gold;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="display">
  <div id="center" data-gap="15">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```