# Dynamically arrange circles around circle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect like in this question:

[Dynamically arrange some elements around a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152390/dynamically-arrange-some-elements-around-a-circle)

I managed to arrange the circles around the big circle. So far no problem. But I also want the small circles to scale on mouseover, while pushing the other small circles away.

Can anybody tell me how to do this? Or recommend a library?

Thank you!

[image: start view]
[image: MouseOver]

Comment: You need to provide some code that you've already tried before we can help you.

Comment: Also, asking for library recommendations is frowned upon as it invites too much debate and opinion on what is supposed to be a problem solving venture.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. Here is a jsfiddle based on the answer I mentioned above. http://jsfiddle.net/y3KJk/1/ At the moment the distance between the circles depends on the number of circles. How can I adjust the distance, if a circle is scaled? Like in my image. Thank you for your help!