# oribitiing circle with out orbiting item

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

i am trying to orbit item around the circle, but the issue is when circle orbit with animation, all the items orbit around themselves.

i want just circle orbit not the items. i write animation on it with transform rotate and here is link of project and codes: https://jsfiddle.net/tg3o4ck2/

here is animation:

```
    @keyframes orbite {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

this animation is add to the container of orbit. items have no animation and i think so that items should not have any animation but i can not understand how can i fix this issue.

Comment: apply the opposite animation to the other elements

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863788/8620333