# How do I position circles in a circle with css/bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I was wondering how I can position circles/images within a circle. I've tried positioning them by putting them in a container and rotating them around a circle but I can't figure out how to make it like the image below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIdkg.png]]

```css
.deg1 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(6em) rotate(-270deg);
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


/* 1 */

.deg2 {
  transform: translate(6em);
}


/* 2 */

.deg3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(6em) rotate(-45deg);
}


/* 3 */

.deg4 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(6em) rotate(-135deg);
}


/* 4 */

.deg5 {
  transform: translate(-6em);
}


/* 5 */

.deg6 {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(6em) rotate(-225deg);
}


/* 6 */

.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  padding: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

.circle-container a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
}

img {
  border-radius: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
  <a href='#' class='center'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg2'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg3'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg4'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg5'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg6'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg1'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
</div>
```

First I tried searching bootstrap's docs for something that can help so I just did this and can't figure it out.

Comment: Show your HTML please

Comment: My bad. Didn't think html was necessary. Updated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I updated it to provide a clear problem, included all the code necessary to replicate.

Comment: `%= image_tag "goldwind.png" %` makes it unable to reproduce the issue, but anyway...  tehre are several approaches for that... and none of them uses bootstrap. Why do you want to use bootstrap for this?

Comment: Sorry please replace `<%= image_tag "goldwind.png" %>` with text or your own image if you please. I was just wondering if I could use bootstrap for this. If not then I'm trying to get the above code to position the way the circles are in the image. I am having trouble putting them in a circle and then having two on the sides on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `translate` and `transform`, you can even position by just using `top`,`left`,'bottom' and 'right'.

> Make sure to use `px` as it will break if you use `%` values.

You need to do some modifications as per your image.

```css
// .deg1 {
//   transform: rotate(270deg) translate(6em) rotate(-270deg);
// } /* 1 */
// .deg2 {
//   transform: translate(6em);
// } /* 2 */
// .deg3 {
//   transform: rotate(45deg) translate(6em) rotate(-45deg);
// } /* 3 */
// .deg4 {
//   transform: rotate(135deg) translate(6em) rotate(-135deg);
// } /* 4 */
// .deg5 {
//   transform: translate(-6em);
// } /* 5 */
// .deg6 {
//   transform: rotate(225deg) translate(6em) rotate(-225deg);
// } /* 6 */
.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  padding: 2.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

.circle-container a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
}

img {
  border-radius: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}

.center img {}

.deg1 img {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.deg2 img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.deg3 img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 85px;
}

.deg4 img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 85px;
}

.deg5 img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 85px;
}

.deg6 img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
  <a href='#' class='center'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg2'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg3'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg4'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg5'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg6'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
  <a href='#' class='deg1'><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSp33aj-dlpojFqHXLPAQlQ9FH-su46mPBwEvFgi97RzuKoC0f1" %></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Javascript/jquery to set the positions of each outer circle.

Jquery shamelessly stolen from [**ThiefMaster♦**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) and their answer at this [**Q & A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152390/dynamically-arrange-some-elements-around-a-circle)

```js
var radius = 50; // adjust to move out items in and out 
var fields = $('.container div'),
  container = $('.container'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
  }
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: #f00;
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear
}

.container div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container div:first-child {
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS to position the elements. For instance, here's an example using CSS grid.

I've declared the grid as 6 rows by 6 columns, in order to position the elements leaving the corners empty.

```css
.circle-container {
  width: 24em; height: 24em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}
.circle-container a {
    display: block;
    border:2px solid grey;
    background:white;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

.deg1 {grid-column:3 / span 2; grid-row: 1 /span 2} /* 1 */
.deg2 {grid-column:1 / span 2; grid-row: 2 /span 2} /* 2 */
.deg3 {grid-column:5 / span 2; grid-row: 2 /span 2} /* 3 */
.deg4 {grid-column:3 / span 2; grid-row: 3 /span 2} /* 4 */
.deg5 {grid-column:1 / span 2; grid-row: 4 /span 2} /* 5 */
.deg6 {grid-column:5 / span 2; grid-row: 4 /span 2} /* 6 */
.deg7 {grid-column:3 / span 2; grid-row: 5 /span 2} /* 7 */


/*bring the lateral circles closer to the center*/
.deg2, .deg5{margin:0 -1em 0 1em;}
.deg3, .deg6{margin: 0 1em 0 -1em}

body{
  background:steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
    <a href='#' class='deg1'>1</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg2'>2</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg3'>3</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg4'>4</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg5'>5</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg6'>6</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg7'>7</a>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use CSS grid (perhaps because of IE11) you can also use whatever grid-like technique you prefer, maybe floats, inline-blocks, maybe even flexbox, positioning the elements in three lines and pushing down the ones on the side.

here's with display:inline-block, which would normally return

```
123
456
7
```

and some transforms to compensate that

```css
.circle-container {
  width: 240px; height: 240px;
  border:2px solid red;
  font-size:0;/*typical inline-block whitespace hack*/
  border-radius:50%;
}
.circle-container a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% / 3);
    height:calc(100% / 3);
    border:2px solid grey;
    background:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1rem;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.deg1, .deg3, .deg4, .deg6{
  transform:translateY(50%);
}

.deg7{
  transform:translateX(100%)
}

body{
  background:steelblue;
}
*{box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
    <a href='#' class='deg1'>1</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg2'>2</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg3'>3</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg4'>4</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg5'>5</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg6'>6</a>
    <a href='#' class='deg7'>7</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust some margin and the width of container then no need to complicate with transform:

```css
.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0.75em auto 0;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.circle-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin:-0.3em -0.1em;
}
a:first-child,
a:nth-child(6) {
  margin-left:2em;
}
a:nth-child(1),a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top:0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
</div>
```