# Is there a way to convert $this from jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Recently fiddled over this question on stackoverflow:

[Dynamically arrange elements around circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152390/dynamically-arrange-some-elements-around-a-circle/10152437#10152437)

But this solutions includes jquery, and $(this) keywords. I want to convert this code:

```
function distributeFields(deg) {
    deg = deg || 0;
    var radius = 200;
    var fields = $('.field'), container = $('#container'),
        width = container.width(), height = container.height(),
        angle = deg || Math.PI*3.5, step = (2*Math.PI) / fields.length;
    fields.each(function() {
        var x = Math.round(width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width()/2);
        var y = Math.round(height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height()/2);
        if(window.console) {
            console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
        }
        $(this).css({
            left: x + 'px',
            top: y + 'px'
        });
        angle += step;
    });
}
```

this is what i tried to do before getting stuck at ($this) keyword:

```
function distributeFieldsJS(deg){
  deg = deg || 0;
  let radius = 200;
  let fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field'), 
  container = document.querySelector('#container'),
  width = container.width(), height = container.height(),
  angle = deg || Math.PI * 3.5, 
  step = (2*Math.PI) / fields.length;
  })
```

Comment: NodeList now has a forEach function. So you can use it. First arg should be the element so you do not need `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside a jQuery `each` callback, so it refers to the element currently being iterated over, so you just need to do

```
for (const field of fields) {
  // refer to `field` here
}
```

and the `field` will be the native DOM element. (just like how `$(this)` referred to the same element wrapped in jQuery).

[getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will give you its dimensions.
`field.textContent` will retrieve its text. `field.style` will give you the [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) of the element.

Comment: or `.forEach(field => ...)` if you don't need to return early.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do i convert the
field.css({left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px'}) to JS?

Comment: @k1st You can assign to the `left` and `top` properties of the [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object of the element being iterated over.