What I want to do is I want to make a circle and find the pixel coordinate on the circle circumference to lay my images on that circle div
So Hello everyone, I have a question that how can I find the pixel coordinates on the circumference of the circle div, because I want to place elements on it dynamically using React/JS by clicking that element, where when I will click on the element it will automatically come on the circle circumference and when I will click more, more will be added equidistant from each other fully dynamically.
And I am not able to figure this out so please someone can point me towards the right direction that how can I achieve the same
In the image I attached I want those red points on the circumference of the white circle (dashed circle).
.
enter image description here
so Click on the link above to reach to the picture
on the right side I have the image and what I want to do is that when I will click on the image on right it gets on the top of the plate image on the circumference.

Don’t bother to work out pixel positions, use rotation of elements centred on the center of the circle. Please show the HTML structure that is relevant to this question and what you have already tried.

Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152390/dynamically-arrange-some-elements-around-a-circle

@Paulie_D yes that is somehow similar to what I want thanks brother for this, I have an idea what can I do now
Have a great day ahead mate

A simple way of doing this, where CSS does the calculations for you, is to put the red dots at the top of rectangles which are anchored at the center of the circle and which rotate an amount dependent on the number of dots.
Here's a basic snippet to show the effect.
Click the button to create another dot.


<style>
  body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .circle {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 50vmin;
    border: dashed 2px white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .point {
    width: 2vmin;
    height: calc(50% + 1vmin);
    top: -1vmin;
    left: calc(50% - 1vmin);
    position: absolute;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 1vmin, red 0, red 1vmin);
    background-position: 0 top;
    background-size: 2vmin 2vmin;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / var(--total) * var(--n)));
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
</style>

<body>tton>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    let n = 0; //no. of dots
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      n++;
      const point = document.createElement('div');
      point.classList.add('point');
      point.style.setProperty('--n', n);
      circle.style.setProperty('--total', n);
      circle.appendChild(point);
    });
  </script>




Brother really thank you for this, this is something I really was trying for from past 3 days and was really frustrated.
Thanks a lot again
I will give it a try and implement it in my game.
Have a great day mate

BTW one doubt, if I want to click on a set of different images and will those images be organised in this similar manner like u demonstrated?

Well, it depends on what you do with them when they are clicked on. You keep the count the same way and make the image the background. But you'd need to show me what the final result is to look like before I could be more specific.

I have added the image (as a link) in the question right below the older image as my reputation is not that high.
so here what I want is I click on the image on the right and it gets to the circumfernce of the plate

Could you show the code that you have tried?
